# JBoss JNP as standalone server and using Resource configs from tomcat's context.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, jndi, context.xml

I have a couple of modules which now have the need of JNDI.
One of these modules runs via Apache Tomcat while the rest run standalone as J2SE application.
I was able to configure the module which uses tomcat without a problem and I've googled a bit and gathered that JBoss JNP can be a good standalone JNDI server to use.
What I fail to understand is how I can reuse the resources definitions which I have already configured (for my module which runs via tomcat in the context.xml file).
Let's say I have the following resource defined in the XML file:

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/dataSource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    driverClassName="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://******
    username="**" password="**"/>
```

And the relevant code which starts the JNP is:

```
System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
NamingBeanImpl jnpServer = new NamingBeanImpl();
jnpServer.start();
```

How can I have an `InitialContext` instance identify the `jdbc/dataSource` binding?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.
You probably can define your jdbs resource in jboss naming context and look it up in your tomcat web app.

More info here: http://www.amitysolutions.com.au/documents/JBossTomcatJNDI-technote.pdf